# Type hinting for a class

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

For example, I have 2 files.

**one.py**:

```
class One:
    def __init__(self, two: Two):
        self.two = two
```

**two.py**:

```
class Two:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

In `class One`, I defined `two: Two`. (argument two will be receive `class Two`)

To type hint, I have to import `class Two` in one.py.

I don't want import the class file to every other files.

I know that there is `object` type, but when I use it, pycharm throws error in class function.

`Unresolved attribute reference ~`

Is there any solution to type hinting for class type?

Comment: [PEP 484 -- Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) has a section on [Forward references](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references) that describes how to handle names that have not been defined yet. Don't know what pycharm would do with them however.

Comment: Pycharm handles the solution given in PEP 484. However, it does not seem to cover the OP's issue.

Comment: The question is not clear to me. You would like to annotate parameter `two` as having type `Two` without importing `Two`, right?

Comment: @user2235698  Exactly right.

Comment: @Hide The only possible solution is to guard import with `typing.TYPE_CHECKING`, see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#runtime-or-type-checking. Otherwise linter would be unable to understand what do you mean by `Two`.